# Is it possible to convert hashed password from one bcypt version to another?

Tags: passwords, password-hashing, blowfish

I have passwords hashed using bcypt version \$2a\$ (e.g. "\$2a\$06\$...") and I want to convert them to version \$2b\$ (e.g. "\$2b\$06$..."). Is it possible to do that? If yes, are there any disadvantages?

Comment: I found this a bit of library usage [see on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733196/where-2x-prefix-are-used-in-bcrypt#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20difference%20between,all%20output%20the%20same%20result.)

Comment: There is no difference between 2a, 2x, 2y, and 2b. If you wrote your implementation correctly, they all output the same result.

Comment: The version $2b$ is not "better" or "stronger" than $2a$. It is a remnant of one particular buggy implementation of BCrypt. But since BCrypt canonically belongs to OpenBSD, they get to change the version marker to whatever they want.